# Is Windows admin priviledge required to install a distribution under Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: administrator, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Activating Windows Subsystem for Linux requires admin priviledge under Windows 10. When it is activated, does admin priviledge still required to install a Linux distribution? Or to get Linux root priviledge?

Comment: No admin privilege is required to install distribution in WSL.

Comment: You can turn it into answer

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Subsystem for Linux is a Windows feature that needs to be enabled
by an administrator in "turn windows features on or off".

Once the feature is enabled, a user may install a Linux distribution from the
Microsoft Store.
Currently available are Ubuntu, Debian, openSUSE, Fedora, Kali, and SLES.